# A dominance order on the relative position matrix corresponds to the closure relation (geometric order) of orbits

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory

The (partial) Springer resolution is defined as a map $\mu: T^*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the partial flag variety consisting of $n$-step partial flags of $\mathbb{C}^d$, and $\mathcal{N}$ a set of nilpotent operators $\mathcal{N} = \{X \in \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^d) : X^n = 0\}$.

To a pair of flags $(F_\bullet, F_\bullet')$ we can consider its *relative position* (matrix, $n \times n$) $a(F_\bullet, F_\bullet')$ given by setting (see e.g. Chriss-Ginzburg p211) $$a_{ij} = \dim \frac{F_i \cap F_j'}{F_{i-1}\cap F_j' \oplus F_i \cap F_{j-1}'}.$$
There is an equivalent definition of these entries (see e.g. Beilinson-Lusztig-MacPherson "A geometric setting for the quantum deformation of $GL_n$" in Duke Math J. 1990): $$a_{ij} = \dim (X_{ij}/X_{i,j-1}),$$ where $X_{ij} := V_{i-1} + (V_i \cap V_j')$ for $1 \leq i \leq n, 0 \leq j \leq n$, and $X_{i,n} = X_{i+1,0}$ for all $i$.
It's not hard to verify that the entries of the relative position matrix are non-negative integers summing up to $d$. Let $M$ denote the set of all $n \times n$ matrices satisfying these two properties.

There's a well known generalisation of the Bruhat decomposition (see e.g. Chriss-Ginzburg Proposition 4.3.15):

> The map $(F_\bullet, F_\bullet') \mapsto a(F_\bullet, F_\bullet')$ is a bijection between $GL_d(\mathbb{C})$-orbits on $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F}$ and the set $M$.

Under this bijection, a matrix $a \in M$ corresponds to an orbit $\mathcal{O}_a$ of a pair of flags.

Finally, there is a matrix dominance order that can be defined on these matrices (see e.g. Chriss-Ginzburg p212, or the above mentioned paper by BLM Section 3.5): say $a \preceq b$ when the following two conditions hold:

1. (for all $i < j$) $$\sum_{r \leq i; s \geq j} a_{rs} \leq \sum_{r \leq i; s \geq j} b_{rs},$$ 2) a very similar formula to above...

Then there is a (supposedly) well-known result (Chriss-Ginzburg Lemma 4.3.19):

> The geometric order/closure relation coincides with the matrix dominance order: $\mathcal{O}_a \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{O}_b}$ if and only if $a \preceq b$.

This is equivalent to the following statement:

> The boundary of $\mathcal{O}_a$ is exactly all orbits $\mathcal{O}_b$ for which $b \prec a$.

Unfortunately I do not know how to prove this, nor where a proof might be found.

The hint says "Using Lemma 4.3.18 : Bruhat order implies with matrix order, and that standard Bruhat order corresponds to closure relation among Schubert varieties", but unfortunately I get nowhere from this.
I am vaguely aware that the forward direction is proven in BLM Lemma 3.6, but their only justification is that "it is obvious from a previous equality", which is not at all obvious to me.

I am asking for either a reference to a proof/outline of proof, or perhaps even some light shed on these mercurial statements.

Answer (score 0):

As Chriss-Ginzburg point out, the fact about the closure relations is proven in

Bernstein, I.N., Gelfand, I.M., Gelfand, S.I., Schubert cells and cohomology of the spaces $G/P$, *Russian Math. Surveys*, **28**,1--26 (1973).

This paper is available on Bernstein's webpage and the statement you want is Theorem 2.11 there. They seem to credit the statement actually to Steinberg, but starting on p. 10, the next page, BGG supply a proof of it.

Comment: The statement in that paper is that the Bruhat order is equivalent to the closure relation among Schubert cells. I am looking for a reference as to how this applies to the results in Ginzburg's book - that the closure relation among orbits in the doubled flag variety correspond to the matrix dominance order.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. I will try to write something helpful about that soon. If you are really just interested in understanding the proof of Theorem 4.1.12 in Chriss-Ginzburg, Ginzburg's 1997 lecture notes prove this in a different way that I do not think requires these facts, but does require perverse sheaves.

Comment: No problem - yes, I am aware a lot of this can be reframed in the language of perverse sheaves and derived categories, but I am looking for a more elementary explanation.